# fomantics-ui change theme settings

Tags: express, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui, hbs

I have fomantic-ui 2.8.8 installed on express 4.161. I'm pretty sure fomantics is working, since in header.hbs I changed the line:
`<div class="ui mini borderless main bottom attached stackable menu ">`

to

`<div class="ui inverted mini borderless main bottom attached stackable menu ">`

and the results was a header that was all black with white text.

But I can't seem to change the default theme settings. Absolutely everything I change in
semantic/src/site or semantic/src/theme has no effect.

That makes zero sense to me. The settings have to be coming from these files.

For instance I changed the file "semantic/src/themes/default/globals/site.variables" from:

@emSize   : 14px;

@inputBackground        : @white;

to:

@emSize   : 34px;

@inputBackground        : @red;

and this had no effect on my web page. I made plenty of other changes of all sorts of variations, but nothing had any effect.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

fomantic-ui was installed using gulp.

Inside the semantic folder is a gulp.js file, a src folder, and a dist folder.

Changing the files in src does nothing until you run "gulp watch" while changing the src files.

Then gulp creates updated "dist/semantic.css" etc. files.
Now, in your .hbs or .html you can reference the new "dist/semantic.css"

(I was missing the "gulp watch" step.)